# отправить список данных на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, битрикс

Есть у меня несколько "услуг" подгруженных из битрикса на html страницу, у них есть название, цена, и то к какой модели машины принадлежит эта услуга. 
Мне нужно при клике на определенную кнопку на странице через ajax отправить данные обо всех услугах в другой файл. Если данная операция возможна проще через get запрос без использования ajax - тоже можно.
Подгруженные услуги выглядят так:

```
<div class="options">
    <div class="option-select__item" data-id="MAZDA 6">
        <h4><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['0']["NAME"] ?></h4>
        <!--<img class="option-line" src="/assets/images/option-line.png">-->
        <h5><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['0']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="option-select__item" data-id="MAZDA 2">
        <h4><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['1']["NAME"] ?></h4>
        <!--<img class="option-line" src="/assets/images/option-line.png">-->
        <h5><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['1']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="option-select__item" data-id="MAZDA 3">
        <h4><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['2']["NAME"] ?></h4>
        <!--<img class="option-line" src="/assets/images/option-line.png">-->
        <h5><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['2']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="option-select__item" data-id="MAZDA CX-5">
        <h4><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['3']["NAME"] ?></h4>
        <!--<img class="option-line" src="/assets/images/option-line.png">-->
        <h5><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['3']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="option-select__item" data-id="MAZDA CX-7">
        <h4><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['4']["NAME"] ?></h4>
        <!--<img class="option-line" src="/assets/images/option-line.png">-->
        <h5><?=$arResult['ITEMS']['4']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?></h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Перед отправкой считать все в массив объектов и превратить его в `json`. И отправить `json`. На стороне сервера сбиндить (или распарсить) `json`. После чего юзать

Comment: К сожалению никогда не работал с json данными, как собрать у каждого элемента данные в массив вроде понятно, ну могли ьы вы на примере показать как это делается?

Comment: Гуглите...по этому материалу оооочень много информации

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="адрес страницы куда отправялется запрос">
// инпуты скрытые, нужны чтобы в запрос добавить инфу
<input style="display:none" name="name" val="<?=$arResult['ITEMS']['0']["NAME"] ?>">
<input style="display:none" name="price" val="<?=$arResult['ITEMS']['0']['PROPERTIES']['PRICE']['VALUE'] ?>">
<input style="display:none" name="car" val="MAZDA_6">
/// и так для каждой машины
..
<button type="submit">текст кнопки по которой отправляется форма</button>
</form>
```

Comment: а что если кнопки как таковой нет, то есть элементы выпадающего списска - это дивы, то есть можно как то использовать то что вы написали выше, но без явной кнопки?
Например можно ли оставить это так без кнопки,  и просто перезагружать страницу используя js ? отправятся ли тогда данные , или нужно обязательно тэз форм, а чтобы отправить только кнопка и при нажатии на див никак отправить не получится?

Comment: в вопросе вы написали " Мне нужно при клике на определенную кнопку на странице через ajax отправить данные обо всех услугах в другой файл", определенная кнопка для каждого автомобиля, или для всей информации? кнопку можно реализовать как баттон из формы. По какому событию будут отсылаться данные в нужный вам файл?